# How should the text file describing mobile app ad providers be handled

Tags: hosting, ads

I understand, that the app-ads.txt file should be hosted under a domain (or a subdomain) root.
The problem is that currently we do not have any registered domain/subdomain, the link we provide in Google play store points to our Facebook page.
I've tried a free app-ads-txt.com service, and it **almost** works, except it would not allow comment strings (starting with "#") and crashes when trying to update the file content with a second google.com entry...

Any suggestions on other ways to host the app-ads.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the next steps and apparently, now it allows # comment strings and it doesn't crash when duplicating a record

1. Visit [app-ads-txt.com](http://app-ads-txt.com)
2. Register an account
3. Add your application
4. Generate your APP-ADS.TXT
5. Publish your APP-ADS.TXT: You will get one link to publish on your Developer Console (Store listing Website option) and wait 24 hours.